# Class to Encapsulate Geometric Units: Radians/Degrees

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, geometry

Did a bunch of coding in computing the geometry of astronomical computations. The resulting code is kind of ugly because things are being converted to and from radians all the time. One of the great things about classes is the ability to encapsulate things like units. So Money is a good example. Although, generally, in Money classes, you tend to see immutable implementations because once we make a piece of money, we are affixing the units and then if we want to change the money, we are going to make a new piece of money with the desired target units.

There are a ton of posts about converting from radians to degrees, and macros. That's not what I am asking. I am asking has anyone else given any thought to do a class like GeometricValue perhaps with a GeometricUnit inside that can be an enum of radians or degrees. In this case, though, I would think what I would want to do is something like this:

```
GeometricMeasure elevationAngle = [[GoemetricMeasure alloc] initWithValue:30 andUnits:GeometricUnits.Degrees];
```

but then a few lines later I could do:

```
double radians = [elevationAngle asRadians];
```

The other thing you could imagine is automatic conversions. I have to say, when the savages went nuts on C++ back at the peak of its run, the arguments that operator overloading was dumb because people could do stupid things and copy converters were also dangerous, I thought were absurd. It would make a lot of sense to be able to do equations like:

```
acos(sin(elevationAngle) + sin(hourAngle))
```

and have the code automatically convert each measure into the desired units for manipulation (radians). Any other people think this is worth considering? or have done something in this direction already (that I couldn't find)?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, exactly, but you may be interested in [Boost Units](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_units.html) (for C++).

Comment: Cool, will look. Have looked at Boost before. Loved some things in it, was kind of revolted by others, but definitely revived strong arguments for the two C++ mainstays of auto conversion and operator overloading.. !

Comment: Probably best to standardize on one system or the other as much as possible... Then perhaps convert from one system to another at display time.